# Syntax Error INSERT INTO Statement (Command Builder)

Tags: database, vb.net

Okay this problem of mine is a little bit tricky for the past months now. 
**SUMMARY:** When I only have 5 columns in my Access Database my code successfully inserts the new row. But when I add another column in my access database (that will be 6 columns now) I encounter

> Syntax Error INSERT INTO Statement

Code:

```
  Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(SYSTEM_MainClient.dbda)
    Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
    dsNewRow = SYSTEM_MainClient.DataSet.Tables("Database").NewRow()
    dsNewRow.Item("First_Name") = TXT_FirstName.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("Last_Name") = TXT_Surname.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("StudentID") = CInt(TXT_StudentID.Text)
    dsNewRow.Item("Middle_Name") = TXT_MiddleName.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("College") = TXT_College.Text
    SYSTEM_MainClient.DataSet.Tables("Database").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
    SYSTEM_MainClient.dbda.Update(SYSTEM_MainClient.DataSet, "Database")
   MsgBox("New Record added to the Database")
```

My database cColumns:

```
"StudentID" (primary key), 
"First_Name", "Last_Name", "Middle_Name"
"College"
```

**RESULT:** This will work okay, and new record is added into the database.

Because there is only 5 columns.

**BUT IF I EXCEED:**

Code:

```
  Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(SYSTEM_MainClient.dbda)
    Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
    dsNewRow = SYSTEM_MainClient.DataSet.Tables("Database").NewRow()
    dsNewRow.Item("First_Name") = TXT_FirstName.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("Last_Name") = TXT_Surname.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("StudentID") = CInt(TXT_StudentID.Text)
    dsNewRow.Item("Middle_Name") = TXT_MiddleName.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("College") = TXT_College.Text

    dsNewRow.Item("Section") = TXT_Section.Text 'I added a section insert

    SYSTEM_MainClient.DataSet.Tables("Database").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
    SYSTEM_MainClient.dbda.Update(SYSTEM_MainClient.DataSet, "Database")
   MsgBox("New Record added to the Database")
```

My database columns:

```
"StudentID" (primary key)
"First_Name", "Last_Name", "Middle_Name"
"College", "Section".
```

It will return an error

> Syntax Error INSERT INTO Statement

It's like it can only insert not more than 5 column values, I think the problem is access not VB itself.

I hope you understand my problem, please help me It's my problem for months now, I searched the forums and Googled it, still can't find the answer.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Perhaps, the problem is with `update command` of the `dbda` can you show it? if problem be with it we will fix it

Comment: `section` is an access reserved word.http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;286335. Try changing it to something else

Comment: This the 'dbda' line .
'Public dbda As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter'  from the top of the class.

Thats all it is, there's no update commands, I think the problem is Access itself because when I delete the "Section" column, everything works fine, but If I added a column again, it will return an error. :(

Comment: Okay, I'll try to change it. Hope it works.

Comment: Oh my god guys! Thank you so much! It works! Thank you very much wholeheartedly I never know that "Section" is a reserved word, my head almost explodes when I can't find the solution, thank you very much! a lesson for me about reserved words. Thank you so much, God Bless!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens almost universally because one or more column names are reserved words or contain spaces or other special characters. In your case I suspect that "section" is a reserved word.

The solution is to set the `.QuotePrefix` and `.QuoteSuffix` properties of the `OleDbCommandBuilder` object to escape all column names. For Access, set them to "[" and "]" respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up :) Really appreciate it :)

Comment: I should note that the best solution is to avoid column names that will cause an issue in the first place.  I would recommend never including spaces or other special characters in a column name and avoiding reserved words.  If you can't or won't do that though, `QuotePrefix` and `QuoteSuffix` are there to support you.